# When I change the activation function of the output layer the model doesn't learn

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to make a binary classifier for sentiment analysis and I'm using the model from the *Basic Text Classification Tutorial in TensorFlow*, which is the next:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Embedding(max_features + 1, embedding_dim),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(1)])
```

This model has a binary accuracy of 80%. However, when I change the activation function of the last layer (the dense layer) to a sigmoid function, the model doesn't learn, the binary accuracy is less than 40%.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Embedding(max_features + 1, embedding_dim),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')])
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: What loss function do you specify when you compile the model?

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you don't specify an activation function the `layers.Dense` uses the default activation function which is `linear` activation function according to [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense), You can read more about the difference between different activation functions and how they work [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/activation-functions-neural-networks-1cbd9f8d91d6#:%7E:text=The%20main%20reason%20why%20we,The%20function%20is%20differentiable.).

Comment: It's true but, it doesn't explain why the default linear function performs better than the sigmoid. The sigmoid function should have equal or better performance as it returns values between 0 and 1.